# Project explorer becomes empty in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Suddenly my `Project Explorer` becomes empty after restart:
[image]

While `C/C++ Project explorer` shows projects:
[image]

Where projects in `Project explorer` are gone and how to get them back?

Comment: Are you using any workings sets?

Comment: Yes, I use working sets

Comment: Well... were you careful which working sets were selected? And if the projects are included in those working sets?

Comment: I was trying to select "Build automatically" that deselects working set, but this not helps. Then I tried to select all available working sets, but Project Explorer remains empty